# What tio think of when converting a web page from HTML 4 to HTML 5

Tags: html, quirks-mode, html4, transitional

I am working on converting a web page from HTML 4 to HTML 5. I have noted that two major differences, which caused me lots of problems, is that class names are case-sensitive in HTML 5 and that statements like "width: 10;" are not allowed in CSS files used by HTML 5 pages, the statements have to be "width: 10px;". One possible reason for my experience is that my HTML 4 documents is in Quirks mode, also known as "HTLM 4 Transitional".

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous differences that make a brief answer nearly impossible.

Here are a few key points and pointers for further research:

- You'll want to switch to a standards based doctype, e.g. `<!DOCTYPE html>`, in order to maximize your compatibility with many browsers.
- The W3C [summary of differences](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/) may be helpful.
- Online scanners, such as the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) or the [IE compatibility check](https://www.modern.ie/en-us/compat-scan) may help flag some issues.
- Many problems (and solutions) are known.  If you're unsure, sites like [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/)?, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/), [HTML5 rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/), and others are immensely useful.

In general, you may find it easier to create a new design from scratch, rather than trying to retrofit an older design to fit new capabilities and design patterns.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance